# Jvectormap markers draw wrong after setFocus call

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I want to focus on US state on selection of an US state. The code is this:

```
    var ddd = {
        "US-VA": 1,
        "US-PA": 1,
        "US-TX": 1,
        "US-RI": 1,
        "US-SC": 1,
        "US-OR": 1,
        "US-CO": 1,
        "US-KY": 1
    };
    var map = {};

  $(function(){
    map = new jvm.WorldMap({
        map: 'us_aea_en',
        backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
        container: $('#us-map'),
        regionsSelectable: true,
        regionsSelectableOne: true,
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#777777',
                "fill-opacity": 1,
                stroke: 'none',
                "stroke-width": 0,
                "stroke-opacity": 1
            }
        },
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: ddd,
                scale: ['#FF6633', '#FF6622'],
                normalizeFunction: 'linear'
            }]
        },
        markerStyle: {
        initial: {
        fill: '#F8E23B',
        stroke: '#383f47'
        }
        },
        markers: [
            {latLng: [41.17, -74.92], name: 'New York'},
            {latLng: [34.06, -118.25], name: 'Los Angeles'},
            {latLng: [29.98, -95.54], name: 'Houston'},
            {latLng: [42.42, -71.3], name: 'Boston'},
            {latLng: [32.79, -96.81], name: 'Dallas'},
            {latLng: [32.79, -79.95], name: 'Charleston'},
            {latLng: [38.02, -122.89], name: 'San Francisco'},
            {latLng: [35.17, -106.86], name: 'Albuquerque'},
            {latLng: [35.72, -97.99], name: 'Oklahoma City'},
            {latLng: [61.22, -149.91], name: 'Anchorage'},
            {latLng: [21.47, -158.08], name: 'Honolulu'}
        ],
        //onRegionSelected: function(event, isSelected, selectedRegions){
        onRegionSelected: function(selectedRegions){
            map.setFocus(9, selectedRegions);
        }
      });
    });
```

When I select a region the markers are drawn in the wrong location. A small shift is seen, like the map try to `setFocus`, but the markers go in the left up corner.
I use **jvectormap-1.1.1.min.js** and **jquery-1.8.3.min.js**

Here is the map when loaded: 
[image]

Here is the map after selecting a state: 
[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

**Change the definition of your `onRegionSelected` method to:**

```
onRegionSelected: function(e, code, isSelected,  selectedRegions){
     map.setFocus(selectedRegions);
}
```

The `setFocus` method expects to receive up to 3 parameters. The first being either the scale, region code, or an array of region codes. The second and third parameters are the `centerX` and `centerY` specifying the center of the viewport.

You were sending the number `9` as the first parameter, and then the second parameter sending the event object and strange things happened.

Also, if you set `regionsSelectableOne: false` for your map, you will see that it zooms to the appropriate level to include the selected regions (states).